# Sharepoint 2007 Current User ObjectModel

Tags: object-model, 2007, user-profile

I'm trying to use the object model of Sharepoint 2007 to make some changes over a list and read users and groups web settings...

For that I developed a Web Service (WCF) that is stored in the same web application as the sharepoint site in IIS.

Thats working.

I call inside the Web service

> SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser

and thats user is not me, is "Sharepoint\System"

Why?

Other thing is that web I try to get all users using

> SPContext.Current.Web.users

that only contain "Sharepoint\System", not the others.

WHY!!!

I give the full trust in the web.config and use the Ntlm authentication method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solutions is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946480/sharepoint-2007-current-user

(the name of the user of the application pool is the same as the loggin user)

Answer (score 0):

Your web service is running as the SharePoint system account, taht's why you get that account as the current user.